# How to set texture storage mode to `private` to texture created from `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`?

Tags: swift, macos, metal, core-video

Xcode's `GPU frame capture` highlight multiple expressions as purple and say I should set the texture storage mode to `private` because only GPU access it. I am trying to fix the purple suggestion.

> Memory Usage'Texture:0x10499ae00 "CoreVideo 0x6000017f2bc0"' has storage mode 'Managed' but is accessed exclusively by a GPU

When using `device.makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)` to create `MTLTexture`, I can set `storageMode` to `private` in the argument `options`.

But when create `MTLTexture` from `CVPixelBuffer` through  `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`, I don't know how to configure the storage mode for the created texture.

Ways I tried:

- Pass a texture attributes dictionary to the `textureAttributes` argument in `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(..., _ textureAttributes: CFDictionary?, ...)`

```
var textureAttrs: [String: Any] = [:]
if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
    textureAttrs[kCVMetalTextureStorageMode as String] = MTLStorageMode.private
}
CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(,,,textureAttrs as CFDictionary,..., &texture)

if let texture = texture,
    let metalTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture) {
        print(metalTexture.storageMode.rawValue)
    }
}
```

My OS is already 10.15.4, but the created `MTLTexture` still has `storageMode` as `managed/rawValue: 1`

- Pass the same attribute to `CVMetalTextureCacheCreate()` which creates the cache for `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` in `cacheAttributes` and `textureAttributes`.

The result is the same.

Problems:

- Is that my attributes dictionary has wrong key-value set? The apple documentation doesn't describe which key and value need to be set.
- Or there is a correct way to configure
- Or currently it does not support yet?

References:

- [makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433429-makebuffer)
- [CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456754-cvmetaltexturecachecreatetexture)
- [CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(*:*:*:*:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456774-cvmetaltexturecachecreate)
- [maxOS 10.15+ kCVMetalTextureStorageMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/kcvmetaltexturestoragemode)

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Did you find anything ?

Comment: @vtruant not yet. Still waiting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Metal and had the same kind of issue. There is no way to change texture `storageMode` one the fly. You have to create another `MTLTexture` with desired `storageMode` and use `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to copy data to it.

Here is the piece of code from my project:

```
    MTLTextureDescriptor* descriptor = [[MTLTextureDescriptor alloc] init];
    descriptor.storageMode = MTLStorageModePrivate;
    descriptor.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm;
    descriptor.width = width;
    descriptor.height = height;

    id<MTLTexture> texture = [__metal_device newTextureWithDescriptor: descriptor];

    if ((data != NULL) && (size > 0)) {
        id<MTLCommandQueue> command_queue = [__metal_device newCommandQueue];
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> command_buffer = [command_queue commandBuffer];
        id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> command_encoder = [command_buffer blitCommandEncoder];
        id<MTLBuffer> buffer = [__metal_device newBufferWithBytes: data
                                                           length: size
                                                          options: MTLResourceStorageModeShared];
        [command_encoder copyFromBuffer: buffer
                           sourceOffset: 0
                      sourceBytesPerRow: (width * 4)
                    sourceBytesPerImage: (width * height * 4)
                             sourceSize: (MTLSize){ width, height, 1 }
                              toTexture: texture
                       destinationSlice: 0
                       destinationLevel: 0
                      destinationOrigin: (MTLOrigin){ 0, 0, 0 }];

        [command_encoder endEncoding];
        [command_buffer commit];
        [command_buffer waitUntilCompleted];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the texture attributes - you muse use the `rawValue` of the `MTLStorageMode`. For example:

```swift
    var textureAttrs: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
        result[kCVMetalTextureStorageMode as String] = MTLStorageMode.managed.rawValue
    }

    var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache!
    let textureCache = CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(
            nil, nil, device, textureAttrs as CFDictionary, &self.textureCache)
```

Once the cache is created with those texture attributes, you can pass nil as the texture attributes in `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` when creating each texture as it will use whatever storage mode the cache was created with. For example:

```swift
      var cvTexture: CVMetalTexture?
      CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil, textureCache, pixelBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &cvTexture)
```

Something to note - I was getting metal warnings in Xcode that my textures should be made private instead of managed, but when setting the cache to a private storage mode, the following error occurred:

`failed assertion 'Texture Descriptor Validation IOSurface textures must use MTLStorageModeManaged'`

This is because these textures are IOSurface-backed. So for now I'm keeping it managed.